# ng new gives dryRunSink.(...).concat is not a function error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new angular project. I followed the steps mentioned in this site. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

When I try to create a new project using `ng new` command, I get error.

```
E:\Code\> ng new some-name
Error: dryRunSink.commit(...).ignoreElements(...).concat is not a function
dryRunSink.commit(...).ignoreElements(...).concat is not a function
```

Here is the result of `ng serve`

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 6.11.4
OS: win32 x64
```

**Edit:** Looks like everyone is getting this error. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9194

Comment: Got the same on node 8.9.4. Seems like bug with new CLI. Git installed

Comment: @R.Richards git?,

Comment: @R.Richards I am not using git at all. Just a simple project,

Comment: @R.Richards did that. Same error again,

Comment: Seems like this issue is now solved, one can install the @latest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem appeared because of a bad commit in source branch. Now it is fixed and hence this problem will not happen again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the link to git issue: https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/380

Solution (temporary solution until they fix the issue):
Adding the following lines to the package.json fixes the problems

```
"@angular-devkit/schematics":"0.0.42", 
"@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.23",
```

To create new project run the following command

```
npm i @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.45 @angular/cli --no-save
```

These solutions were provided in the git issue,

Comment: I think it is fixed in latest release, try to get that,

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the Angular CLI and reinstalling it again:

```
$  npm uninstall @angular/cli
$  npm cache clean
$  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

To ensure you have the latest version. IF the problem persists, try updating the Node version (6.11.4 is a bit old). You can use nvm to update your node version. Download and install the package from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), then run

```
$  nvm install 8.9.0 // for example, you can have another version
$  nvm use 8.9.0 // or the version you have installed
```

If this STILL persists, we can assume there is a problem with `@angular/cli`. You can try downgrading it. Remove it again and then

```
$  npm install -g @angular/cli@1.1.2 // for example
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Upgraded node as well, but still same error,

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the new version of the CLI. You may want to downgrade to an earlier version. I have updated the answer with an instruction

Comment: Looks like everyone is getting this error. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9194

Comment: Yes, I see. And yes, this is the latest version you have, then downgrade maybe to v1.6.3, should be okay. Then you may upgrade to a newer version, which would contain a fix for this issue

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem here, just fixed with @angular/cli 1.6.5

```
$ npm uninstall @angular/cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

And in my project folder:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules dist
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
$ npm install
```

Now I can generate projects, components, etc normally

Answer (score 1):

> **Status**
>
> This issue has been resolved in version 1.6.6.
>
> **Updating**
>
> The steps to update your environment to the latest version containing
>   the fix:
>
> ```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> npm cache clean
> # if npm version is > 5 then use `npm cache verify` to avoid errors (or to avoid using --force)
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
>
> rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
> npm install
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The issue of [rxjs operator] is not a function is a result of the
>   migration of the devkit repo to using "pipeable" (formerly "lettable")
>   operators instead of the prototype patching approach that the Angular
>   CLI was using prior to release 1.6.6 (which was just released). The
>   commit which fixed it is here.
>
> The issue is that the CLI was using operators that were not imported
>   and relied on them being on the Observable object. When the devkit was
>   updated it removed this function and the bug in the CLI was exposed.
>   The latest version of the CLI is now using pipeable operators and
>   therefore importing all of the operators needed to work with
>   observables, so this issue has been resolved.

Explanation by Brocco:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9194#issuecomment-360615868

Answer (score 1):

below command working for me.

```
CMD : npm install @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.45 @angular/cli --no-save
```

Comment: Best if you don't want to update your local cli rather than global

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes installing this packages:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.0.36",
"@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.22",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.42",
"@schematics/angular": "^0.1.11",
"@schematics/schematics": "0.0.11"
```

And it works now

[My Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPxNd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On angular/cli 1.6.4 I was getting "Error: dryRunSink.commit(...).ignoreElements is not a function"

The newest version has it fixed on @angular/cli: 1.6.5, you can check it out by installing it by running the following:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

be sure to install the dev so you can run things like npm start(ng serve) and run your proyect by installing:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Worked great for me.